# Classification of non-stationary acoustic signals

Tags: cnn, audio-recognition

I'm currently working on a task of classification of short non-stationary audio signals with length of 1024 elements and sampled at 120 kHz.

I was wondering if there are any special techniques or models for classification of such signals. As far as I know, most of solution for this kind of tasks relies on computation of FFT/MFCC or  spectrograms. But due to  non-stationary nature of features, I can't compute statisticaly reliable frequency based features.

Also approach with CNN as described in the article [Raw Waveform-based Audio Classification Using Sample-level CNN Architectures](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.00866.pdf) shows promising results, but still doesn't work good enough.

Can anyone advice me another approaches or thoughts where to start from? Will appreciate any help!

Comment: So the sounds are 8ms long (1024 @ 120kHz)? Can you provide an example of the signal?

Comment: Have you tried very short spectrogram with very short windows? Say 128,64, or even 32 or 16, elements long?

Answer (score 1):

As you try to classify sequential data, you can try simple recurrent neural network or their advance version LSTMs - but as you have a short signal, RNN should work fine.

You can read this paper on [sound classification with LSTM](http://ceur-ws.org/Vol-2125/paper_134.pdf) and this  [medium article](https://towardsdatascience.com/using-cnns-and-rnns-for-music-genre-recognition-2435fb2ed6af)